# Argparse command line interface

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I need to enter 5 values but one command it should ask one by one

```
my_parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
my_parser.add_argument('id', help='Enter id')
my_parser.add_argument('url', help='Enter url')
my_parser.add_argument('days', help='Enter days')
my_parser.add_argument('param', help='Enter param')
my_parser.add_argument('code', help='Enter code')
my_parser.add_argument('thread', help='Enter thread')
my_parser.add_argument('file', help='Enter file')
args = my_parser.parse_args()
```

In this I need to pass the values in a single shot

I need the values to be passed one by one

Comment: I posted a way to intake multiple values at the sam time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, `argparse` is not intended for your use case. Please check if `input()` is what you need as demonstrated in below code.

```
id = input("Enter id\n")
print(id)
url = input("Enter url\n")
print(url)
days = input("Enter days\n")
print(days)
param = input("Enter param\n")
print(param)
code = input("Enter code\n")
print(code)
thread = input("Enter thread\n")
print(thread)
inputfile = input("Enter file\n")
print(inputfile)
```

Comment: This is the one I was expecting it works ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.It allows to take 6 values at a time

```
url, days, param, code, thread,inputfile   = input("Enter your url,days,param,code,thread,inputfile : ").split()
```